# What is the best value for MaxOpenPreparedStatements for DBCP for BasicDataSource

Tags: jdbc

I am using DBCP framework where i am creating BasicDataSource.
Here since same queries with different parameters are going to fired, i want to enable prepared statement pooling.
I have set MaxOpenPreparedStatements to 100 for sometime the perfromance was good, but slowly it started degrading. What would be best values for MaxOpenPreparedStatements

Comment: There is not a single 'best' value. It will depend on your application and its exact behaviour. Only you can determine this by measuring and experimenting and maybe loadtesting your application.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i am doing the experiment, thought what would be too high or too less based on someones experience.